# Why add acid to rid of soluble carbonate or hydroxide impurities? Will it not also react with halide I'm testing for

Tags: halides, hydrogen, silver

When identifying metal halides with silver ions, the positive ion $\ce{Ag+}$ will form $\ce{AgX}$ with halide in a solution. However, $\ce{H+}$ is added (typically in the form of an acid like $\ce{HNO3}$) to solution to get rid of $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ ions first. Will the $\ce{H+}$ not also react with the halide $\ce{X-}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydrogen halides are strong acids, meaning that their conjugate bases $\ce{X-}$ are extremely weak. Thus, adding $\ce{H+}$ will neutralize stronger bases such as $\ce{OH-}$ first before $\ce{X-}$.